# How to compare data? Size of rocks

Tags: anova, group-differences

I have data for the size of rocks for two independent locations, A and B.

Data lists rock size from smallest to largest (shown by yellow column)

Red column shows the percentage of rocks under that size (out of 100%)

Green columns shows cumulative percentage (out of 100%)

**Normality test indicates rock data (yellow columns) is not normally distributed.**

**When I apply log transform to the data, it becomes normally distributed, and shows a straight (linear) line when plotted on a graph**

**I want to compare rock sizes between the two locations**

**What is the best way to compare rock sizes (yellow columns) given that these values are thresholds, not actual rock sizes?**

e.g.

[image]

Comment: Could you please post your data in a readable format (say, link to a csv-file?), not as an image?